# Light speed working on private window(incognito) while not working in normal window of a browser

Tags: wordpress, browser-cache, cache-control, lightspeed, sitespeed

My site is hosted on lightspeed webserver also using lightspeed plugin for optimization it working for private window but not working on normal window of my browser
here is header request of both windows

1. private window(incognito)
   Response Header
   X-Dns-Prefetch-Control: on
   X-Litespeed-Cache: hit
2. Normal window
   Response Header
   X-lightspeed-cache-Control: private,max-age=1800
   X-Litespeed-Cache: miss

please tell me why it is not working on normal window is there any plugin configuration miss or any server configuration is miss?

Light speed cache should work the same as work in private window. In normal window it is missing the hit. Cache should also work in normal window but it is not working.

Comment: This site is for questions about programming

Comment: If you refresh again in the private window, are you still getting a cache miss? Maybe you can post it on https://serverfault.com/ since the question is not programming related.

Comment: I am getting hit on refresh browser again.